# AS3/Java/HTML: Get flash to respond to external html/java events

Tags: java, html, actionscript-3, web, mouseover

I want my flash movie to respond to rollover type events for links on my website. The idea being that the flash movie will provide descriptions of the links when moused over, but if the user doesn't have flash the functionality isn't lost. What's the best way to do this (if it's possible)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the ExternalInterface class to provide functions that javascript can call

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000340.html